# no match for 'operator!=' in checking while loop

Tags: c++

```
struct dic
{
    string key;
    int code;
};
dic H[71];
```

Now using `key` in the condition of the `while`-statement gives me an error.

```
while ((H[h].key)!= NULL)
{

}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'H[h].dic::key != 0'
```

Comment: An object can't be `NULL` in C++.

Comment: Because C++ "string" is not  pointer then you can't compare it with NULL. It may be empty (zero length) but not NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type of `dic::key` is `string`, and you are trying to compare it to an integer (`NULL == 0`), which is not implemented.  You need to check if the string is empty:

```
while (!H[h].key.empty()) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key of the element is a string. You can not compare a string to `NULL` as it is an object not a pointer. The macro NULL will most probably either defined as a pointer or an int value and neither of those is comparable to string.

Answer (score 0):

The macro `NULL` is often defined to either `0` or `(void *) 0`, none of those values can be used when comparing to a `std::string` (unless, of course, you implement your own custom comparison operator, which you shouldn't).

If you want to check if a string is empty, use [`std::string::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to say:

```
if (H[h].key.empty()) { ... }
```